# Why is my shell history not written sometimes, and how can I fix this?

Tags: bash, signals, zsh

Sometimes my shell history isn't written. I think it might be when a shell exits because of certain signals, like when the OS is shutting down. So:

1. is it true that bash and/or zsh don't write out their history when terminating as a response to certain signals?
2. is there a way to hook into these signals and tell the shell to still write history?

I would rather not have it write history after each command.

Comment: Why don't you want to write after each command? I don't notice it happening, and I have a very long Bash history (about 100k commands).

Comment: There is no cross-shell way of doing this. Please pick one shell.

Comment: please tell me how to do it for all popular shells

Comment: What are the popular shells? And even if you give a list, that's too broad a question for Stack Overflow. (Ignoring the fact that this is border-line off-topic, anyway. Shell usage questions probably belong on unix.stackexchange.com.)

Answer (score 3):

Your history command store in RAM until you regularly terminate your terminal. Then list of your command write into the .bash_history.
If you wanted to write your commands history at anytime you need, use below command:

```
#history -a
```

Based on history command manual `-a append history lines from this session to the history file`